# Why does rospy::wait_for_message get stucked even though messages are being published?

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using this method in my python script

```
rospy.wait_for_message("/my_topic", Bool, timeout=None)
```

The `/my_topic` messages are being published, I can see them when running `rostopic echo /my_topic`. But the script stays at the `rospy.wait_for_message` line as if it couldn't detect any messages. What could be the cause?

---

EDIT

```
$ rostopic echo -n1 /my_topic 
data: True
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323600/why-does-rospy::wait_for_message-get-stucked-even-though-messages-are-being-published?/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-05-21**:
wait_for_message is explicitly meant to get just one message on the topic. Does it detect at least one message?
If you need to continuously receive the data on /my_topic, you need a [Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers).

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2019-05-21**:
@curi_ROS no, it doesn't detect any message. Not even one.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-21**:
What is the output of `rostopic echo -n1 /my_topic`?

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2019-05-21**:
@gvdhoorn It outputs the message.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-21**:
I actually wanted to make sure that `/my_topic` is of type `Bool`. Because if it isn't, things won't work. I also wanted to make sure that `/my_topic` actually exists, and is not namespaced. Without you showing us that, we cannot help you.

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2019-05-21**:
@gvdhoorn ok, I didn't understand what you wanted me to do. The question is now edited with the output of this command.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-21**:
Then I guess we'll need to see some of your code. Specifically how you initialise everything up to and including where you use `wait_for_message(..)`.

It doesn't necessarily need to be your exact code, as long as it reproduces the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've experienced the exact same problem and I noticed I was using the `wait_for_message()` method before initializing the node using `rospy.init_node()`.

So, the solution would be calling the `init_node()` method before any publishing/subscribing (which is done implicitly by the `wait_for_message()` method). Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [pale](https://answers.ros.org/users/42680/pale/) with karma: 66 on 2019-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5